# как сделать чтобы контейнер был одно высоты и ширины?

Tags: html, css

есть 4 контейнерa, они находятся во flex'е и их ширина - 25%.
как сделать так, чтобы их высота равнялась ширине. js - не выход
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648733/make-a-div-square-when-there-is-a-dynamically-changing-width-based-on-percenta

Comment: @Zhihar, у нас и русская версия есть :)